# How to embebed javafx 2.1 in an installation package

Tags: exe, javafx-2, software-distribution, dmg

I need to distribute a javafx 2.1 application but the client doesn't want to be asked if he wants to install javafx 2.1. It should be automatically installed. Does someone know how to wrap it in a dmg and in an exe package??

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tutorial here: http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/packaging-javafx-applications-as-native/

and there (although for 2.2): https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx

Comment: Hi Sergey, I already tried but I couldn't do it. I think that the problem is the jar file for javafx (in the tutorial, the jfxrt). Does it need to contain all the jars included in the jnlp file (http://dl.javafx.com/1.3/javafx-rt.jnlp) ??

Comment: You are referencing jnlp for old JavaFX 1.3. You need to take jfxrt.jar from JavaFX 2.1 SDK.

Comment: Ok. I have another approach to follow the tutorial but still not working: 

1. I download the javafx2.2 sdk package (javafx_sdk-2_2_0-beta-b11-macosx-universal-30_may_2012.zip)

2. I download the samples for javafx2.2 (javafx_samples-2_2_0-beta-b11-macosx-universal-30_may_2012.zip) 

I tried to build the dmg with one of the samples and the jar that is included in the rt/lib folder but it's not working. I tried to set as a main class both: the javafx Main class and the one for the project but the application is not working, do you know if I'm doing something wrong???

Thank you again.

Comment: I discover some errors in the console:  
6/5/12 11:25:53.535 AM [0x0-0x300300].brickbreaker.Main: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/ana/Desktop/Desktop-brickBreaker2.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libglass.dylib
6/5/12 11:25:53.535 AM [0x0-0x300300].brickbreaker.Main:  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:276)
6/5/12 11:25:53.535 AM [0x0-0x300300].brickbreaker.Main:  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:122)...

Comment: better try stable version -- download jdk7u4+Fx2.1 cobundle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Yes, actually, it is the one that I'm using right now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got it !!!!

I'm going to explain how I got it from my perspective. Sorry if it sounds a little bit dummy but I'm not used to build desktop applications and with a new technology as javafx is even more difficult for me.

1. Download the latest version of the jdk (in this case the 7.0 one).
2. Follow the steps from the tutorial and include your .jar and the jfxrt.jar
3. As a main class I set com.javafx.main.Main
4. Create the application and now, the most important part:
5. Once the application has been created, open it (right click on the app and "show package content". Go to the folder: Content/Resources/Java.
6. Do the same operation with the vm: go to /Java/JavaVirtualMachines and right click on the 1.7.0.jdk to open the Contents folder.
7. **Copy ALL the .jar and .dylib from the jdk to the java resources in your application**
8. Run the application and it will work :)